# javascript custom pattern validation type

Tags: javascript, php, validation, design-patterns, input

Is it possoble to create a custom input pattern?
For example:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Your email" name="email" required="required" pattern="validate-unique-email" class="myclass-1">
```

Where:

-validate-unique-email - is a custom pattern.

But I can't submit my form with this pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean `unique email`, unique email against the db records?

Comment: wellyou can write up your own validation, ajax the input then check, here is an [idea](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/), and remember, never rely on client side validation alone. this is too broad anyway

Comment: My pattern is not regular expression. And I would like to pass validation...

Comment: i understand, and yes you need to validate email addresses from your db, then you're going to have to request from the server

Answer (score 0):

Right answer: `<input type="email" placeholder="Your email" name="email" required="required" pattern="\validate-unique-email\" class="myclass-1">`